# Running dracut on AWS EBS Centos 7 prevents booting

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, dracut

I have a minimal Centos 7 build. When I run dracut --force, it builds a new initramfs that is 20mb smaller. The only difference in the modules section is an absence of qemu.

```
localhost login: [ 3322.193617] Restarting system.
[    0.000000] Cannot get hvm parameter CONSOLE_EVTCHN (18): -22!
[    0.817440] Cannot get hvm parameter CONSOLE_EVTCHN (18): -22!
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Paths.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Basic System.
[  123.897756] dracut-initqueue[273]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
[  124.410440] dracut-initqueue[273]: Warning: dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

The boot process for an HVM EC2 instance appears to still require xen-blkfront. However, these are not detected when dracut rebuilds, nor do they show up with modprobe on the running system. I added them using the example in [this post](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2014-June/450604.html) and it successfully rebooted.

Comment: Why are you using HVM with a Linux server?

Comment: "For the best performance, we recommend that you use current generation instance types and HVM AMIs when you launch your instances." -- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html

Comment: Perhaps my problem is that they should be using the PV drivers even with HVM. So maybe that is something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have more generic `initramfs` to support various types of AWS instance, such as modern M5/C5/t3a, enhanced networking adapter (ENA), EBS optimized disk, nvme, generic xen-blkfront ... etc...
You should disable dracut option host-only. (In CentOS default is on)

In short:

```
dracut -f -v -N
```

OR

```
yum install dracut-config-generic
dracult -f -v
```

Double check: (you should see drivers for ena, xen, nvme, xen-blkfront, etc.)

```
lsinitrd | grep "ena\|xen\|nvme"
```

And remember to make sure your /etc/fstab using UUID to map partition instead of device name such as /dev/sdx